# Drop down data showing up without any dropdown in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am preparing a excel sheet with few dropdown and cells without any dropdown at all. For some reason the free cells are showing dropdown data when i press alt and down arrow key.

I have checked there are no validation rules on these cells and i am not able to figure out the reason for this problem

I have tried copying over free cells and validating the validation rules

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Remember that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd> will display a set of optional inputs based on the entries above.  Here I use it with **D3** active:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

The shortcut first looks for DV.
If present, the DV list is displayed and the cells above are ignored.
if not present, the shortcut checks the cell above.
If the cell above is empty, empty is displayed.
Otherwise cell values from above are displayed.

Comment: This creates a confusion for the other people, how can i prevent it?

Comment: @Atul  See my **EDIT#1**